# Joining a table with max value from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I currently have 2 tables some call information.
1st table contains the call list joined with the user list, second one contains the login logout informaiton.

I have to add the status column (shown below) to the first table, pulled where user's last logTable.xtime that is less than table1.time

Basically 'what was this users last status before this call'.

**callTable**

```
callID userID time
1      15     xx:xx
1      16     xx:xx
2      15     xx:xx
2      16     xx:xx
```

*logTable*

```
userID    xtime   status
15        xx:xx    t
15        xx:xx    f
.
.
.
.
16        xx:xx    f
16        xx:xx    t
.
.
.
.
```

I managed to pull last xtime for all users but since I do not have the first table's time, it returns the latest status. But if I blindly join the tables, it becomes a messed up table.

```
select q2.uid, q2.xtime,q3.status
from
(select uid,max(xtime) as xtime
from table2

--where xtime<time from table1!!!!!!

group by uid
) q2
left join table2  q3
on q2.uid=q3.uid and q2.xtime=q3.xtime
```

Since I do not have the time value from the first table at the commented point, I cannot filter the table accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, a relative simple method is a lateral join:

```
select ct.*, lt.status
from callTable ct left join lateral
     (select lt.*
      from logTable lt
      where lt.userId = ct.userId and lt.time <= ct.time
      order by lt.time desc
      fetch first 1 row only
     ) lt
     on lt.userId = ct.userId;
```

This can take advantage of an index on `logTable(userId, time desc)`.

Comment: Thanks,
I actually have never heard of this keyword. Will look deeper at it now.